# Can't tell apart multiple lines with geom_line(). Is there a quick solution for this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm currently using ggplot to build slope plots with 17 lines (each representing a different man) for a study I'm running. However, I can't tell some of the colours of the lines apart. (I've attached an example below so you can see what I mean).

I had assumed there'd be a parameter I could change to allow a mix of colours, thicknesses and textures (dotted or dashed) to make it easier to tell what each line refers to in a slope chart with 10+ lines. However, I haven't found any recommendations for this so far. Does someone know of something like this, or will I have to define some logic to add this kind of aesthetic?

Thank you, J

[image]

Comment: You could add `scale_color_manual()` to apply a palette or values you specify. Alternatively, you could find a pre-set palette with enough options to color each individual on your plot, such as `ggthemes::scale_color_tableau('Tableau 20')`. Regarding varying `linewidth` or `linetype`, you could certainly map something to either or both aesthetics to help differentiate between individuals or groups. We'd need to see some of the data structure to produce a more specific solution.

Comment: consider using `directlabels` package to add the line names directly to the plot and avoid having any legend

Answer (score 2):

Above around 8 or so colors, it becomes very difficult to differentiate among the values.  There's some color science you can examine to understand how the values are separated in some colorspaces, one simple place to play around would be with the Brewer color scales, which has some visualizations of how easily you can differentiate with the [tool available online here](https://colorbrewer2.org/).

You can get around this limitation by combining legends for color and, for example, linetype, but you have to address the values manually to do so in a way that combines them simply.

In this case, here's an example that shows how to combine `color` and `linetype` so that we represent the same 9 colors from one of the Brewer color scales with two different linetypes to get 17 different color + linetype combinations.

## Example Combining `color` and `linetype`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(RColorBrewer)

df <- data.frame(
  lots=rep(LETTERS[1:17], 3),
  x= rep(1:3, each=17),
  y_adj = rnorm(17*3)
)

df$y <- c(1:17, 2:18, 3:19) + df$y_adj

p <-
  ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=lots)) +
  geom_line(linewidth=0.5)
```

The plot without optimization looks like this

[image]

To create the scale, I manually grab the 9 values from the "Set1" Brewer scale and set both color and linetype manually via `scale_*_manual(values=)`.  The final scale is set so that most colors repeat once and linetype follows the same pattern: solid for the first 9, then dashed for the next 8.

```
my_colors <- brewer.pal(9, name="Set1")  # Brewer color scale used.  We need 9

p + aes(color=lots, linetype=lots) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values=c(my_colors, my_colors[1:8])  # 9 colors + 8 colors = 17
  ) +
  scale_linetype_manual(
    values=c(rep("solid",9), rep("dashed",8))  # 9 linetype + 8 linetype = 17
  )
```

[image]

## Alternative: Change Your Visualization

When you are faced with a lot of categories and this issue, it's a good time to think if there's a different way to visualize the data.  One approach is to consider the dimensions of your plot first, and think if there's a better way to represent this in a plot.  The base plot OP shared (and the reprex shown here) have 3 dimension:

- `y`: here represents a range from 0 to 26+ in the reprex
- `x`: here represents only 3 values (1, 2, and 3)
- `lots`: represents 17 differen values

As OP has seen, it's difficult to represent a lot of values in the `color` or `linetype` or `shape` dimensions, whereas it's easy to show lots of values in either X or Y axis.  Since there are **lots** of values for `lots`, and only 3 values for `x`, why not shift the plot so that `lots` is the X axis and `x` is the color axis?  Here, it's probably best to represent with a bar or column plot and group along `lots`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=lots, y=y, fill=factor(x))) +  # use factor(x) to force discrete
geom_col(width=0.8, position=position_dodge2())
```

[image]